# How to increase font-size in Docker console log?

Tags: docker

How to increase font-size in Docker console log?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to play around with application DPI by right-clicking on docker-desktop app > Properties > Compatibility ? `For docker on windows`

Comment: It's currently not possible. There is an open pull request with a change to enable this but it's been open since 2016. https://github.com/docker/kitematic/pull/1479/files

You are better of using features within your operating system.

Comment: On Ubuntu KDE, I can increase the font size in Docker Desktop with `Ctrl`+`+` (more precisely, `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`=`). Truth to say, this increases the font of the entire DD interface, which is not very convenient, but as a temporary solution it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can use shortcuts below:

```
CTRL + to increase zoom level
CTRL - to reduce zoom level
CTRL 0 to reset zoom level
```